# Microphone problem on ASUS S400CA with Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: asus, 15.04, microphone

I had Ubuntu 14.04 LTS install on my laptop, but as the microphone didn't work I tried to install the 15.04 version, but the microphone still doesn't work. Any idea of what should I do to make the microphone work?